# utility "less" takes high cpu

Tags: linux, less

I'm using suse 9 and redhat 5. Sometimes I see that "less" takes a lot of cpu. It happens more on suse 9 though happened on redhat 5 too. I have to admit that the frequency of such event is very low - somewhat once in several months. I would appreciate if you can give me some hints why it could happen. Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you execute that you see high usage by `less`?

Comment: @Shahbaz: Then, won't the question be appropriate for Unix.SE

Comment: @Aditya, it most certainly is.

Comment: can you supply more details? are you viewing large files? Does the file have long lines? What options (-S? -R?) Is there a .lessrc? Are you showing line numbers? Which version of coreutils is this? What does `type less` say? What are the locale settings (try `LANG=C less`?) What is the terminal emulator? Are you working remotely (ssh/screen/tmux?) etc. etc.

Comment: suse 9 is horribly out of date. UPGRADE you will have better everything.  openSuSE is at 12.3.  I had suse 9 and it was awful compared to 12.

Answer (score 0):

It's far more likely that a command you are piping to `less` is taking up a lot of CPU.  It's also possible that you are having it page a very large file (or data stream) and it's just doing some work on an otherwise busy system, and it floats up on your `top`.

Don't spend time staring at a process monitor and worrying about it, especially for something that happens on an interval of months.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since you ask for "hints on why this might happen", my comment qualifies as an answer :)

- large files could cause high CPU usage (especially with, e.g. line numbering and UNICODE perhaps with a lot of ANSI escapes that cancel each other out?)
- Does the file have long lines? Long lines can cause problematic performance with wrapping
- What options (-S? -R?) ('munging' ANSI sequences or control characters may take time while not being visible)
- Is there a .lessrc? (It may contain hidden options responsible for the high CPU)
- What is the terminal emulator? Are you working remotely (ssh/screen/tmux?) etc. etc.

Various things

- Are you showing line numbers?
- Which version of coreutils is this?
- What does `type less` say?
- What are the locale settings (try `LANG=C less`?)